# How can I obfuscate only com.foo.* but excluding com.foo.bar.*? (Proguard)

Tags: java, android, proguard

I tried:

```
-keep class !com.foo.** { *; }
-keep class com.foo.bar.** { *; }
```

but it obfuscates classes other than com.foo.* (which I don't want)

I also tried:

```
-keep class !com.foo.**, com.foo.bar.** { *; }
```

and it fails to parse.

Answer (score 0):

From your description I understand that you want to keep everything in the `com.foo.bar` package (+ subpackages?). You can achieve this by the following rule:

```
-keep class com.foo.bar.** { *; }
```

The `**` pattern will match also subpackages, if you only want to current package, use `*` instead.

If you use a rule like this:

```
-keep class !com.foo.** { *; }
```

you will actually keep everything but com.foo.**, so you should be careful with exclusion patterns. Always include at least one inclusion pattern afterwards. The exclusion pattern should be more specific as the inclusion pattern, see below.

This rule should parse correctly (just tested it), but will not work, as ProGuard will stop evaluating a rule once it finds a match:

```
-keep class !com.foo.**, com.foo.bar.** { *; }
```

The exclusion pattern `!com.foo.**` will match everything in com.foo and subpackages, thus it will also match com.foo.bar.

Comment: Please let me clarify. I want to keep all classes except that are under com.foo.*. Also com.foo.bar.* should be kept too.

Comment: So in the end, I want to obsfucate only **com.foo.*** while excluding **com.foo.bar.***